# How can I set an Enum list contain chars as *, /, -, % and +

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, enums, char

I writing a calculator program and have some major operators like `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `%`.

I want to create an enumerable that contains those characters for checking user input.

How is that possible?

Comment: To be honest, why bother using these symbols? You could simply write words down, like an enum with Sum, Multiply, Divide, Subtract etc..?

Comment: You right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can not declare a Char type as a base for Enum. However, you can use this workaround with extension methods:

```
enum Sign // ASCII codes
{
    Mod = 37, // '%'
    Mul = 42, // '*'
    Add = 43, // '+'
    Sub = 45, // '-'
    Div = 47  // '/'
}

static class SignExtension
{
    public static Char ToChar(this Sign s)
    {
        return (s as IConvertible).ToChar(null);
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Sign op = Sign.Add;

        Char c    = op.ToChar();   // c == '+'
        String s1 = op.ToString(); // s1 == "Add"
        String s2 = c.ToString();  // s2 == "+"
    }
}
```

Be careful, Sign.ToString() will not give the desired result. You must call Sign.ToChar().ToString() to convert your Sign to String

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 enum chars1 { plus = '+' , minus='-' };
```

then you could use it like

```
char newChar =(char)chars1.plus;
```

Comment: plus.ToString() returns "plus" instead of "+"

Answer (score 0):

Here's ***a*** "way" to do it:

```
class Operations
{
    public static string Plus = "+";
    public static string Minus = "-";
    public static string Times = "*";
    public static string Divide = "/";
}
```

and use:

```
if (input == Operations.Plus) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want create an enumerable that contains above characters ...

```
string s = "+-*/%"
```

This is what you need.

> ... to checking user operator input validation

It's simple:

```
if (s.Contains(userInput)) { ...
```

Assuming `userInput` is what the user choose.